# node.js express not returning default page

Tags: node.js, express

In this code

```
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(history({
    index: 'Trading Inquiry/index.html'
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Trading Inquiry')));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(1);
    res.sendFile('Trading Inquiry/index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('My site started at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

I set it up so that links are relative to the folder `Trading Inquiry`. Plus ig the `/` route is given, return the index.html file, and for routes that don't match, then also return the index.html file. However when I visit http://localhost:3000, I get

```
Cannot GET /
```

This works though

```
http://localhost:3000/index.html
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Works on my computer when I comment out app.use(history({index: 'Trading
Edit: Also works if I use app.use(history()) without any index parameter

Answer (score 1):

`res.sendFile` doesn't use express public path, so you have to mention the absolute path of file while sending it.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'Trading Inquiry', 'index.html'));
```

**Another solution(the one I prefer)**,

If you provide '/' as first argument for express static middleware, the the file name `index.html` will be rendered.

So if you change below line:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Trading Inquiry')));
```

You will not need a get route for `index.html`, so below code is not required.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(1);
    res.sendFile('Trading Inquiry/index.html');
});
```

Comment: But if I do this, any other files in the root folder will be accessible?

Comment: @omega, Yeah other routes will also work. And I don't understand why are you using 'connect-history-api-fallback' , it's usually used for a Single page Application having single index.html , so if you remove " app.use(history(...)) ", all the routes will work fine

Comment: It needs a general fallback, because if I use history api, links generated could be like `/customers/5`, though the fodler structure doesn't exist server side, its virtual. Then if I copy that link to another tab, you get 404. Thats why server side needs a general catch all to return index.html.